# Is 'expanse' an acceptable synonym for 'surface'?

Tags: synonyms

Is 'expanse' an acceptable synonym for 'surface'?

Comment: Do you have a particular context in mind?

Comment: Yeah, it _can_ be. When it does make an appropriate synonym it would probably make a great synonym. But without context you get to decide on your own.

Comment: Going by this and your other question, [What is the difference between 'roof' and 'canopy'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17807/what-is-the-difference-between-roof-and-canopy), I cannot help but wonder if you are reading or analyzing something to do with the creation story in Genesis!

Comment: I am reading the Quran, I'm a Muslim...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A surface is something that can be mapped to a flat plane, like the surface of the Earth can be viewed on a paper map.

An *'expanse'* is not limited to only two dimensions.  The 'expanse of the Sahara desert' is usually considered as a two-dimensional surface, but the 'expanse of space' is at least three dimensions and probably many more.  The 'expanse of the Pacific ocean' can refer to the surface ***area*** only, or it can include all the ***volume*** of water that extends downward from the surface into the deepest trenches.

Answer (score 4):

*Surface* has many (related) meanings. *Expanse* is synonymous to *area*, so it is also synonymous to *surface* when the latter is used in the meaning of *surface area*. Overall, I'd say in most contexts, *expanse* is not an acceptable substitution for *surface*.

Comment: To expand on this, _expanse_ is generally used to refer to large areas of land. _Surface_, while applicable, is generally not used for this, so it's even less likely that they would be used as synonyms.