# What is the difference between 'roof' and 'canopy'?

Tags: differences

What is the difference between 'roof' and 'canopy'? And would you describe the sky as the roof of the earth or the canopy of the earth? (*Sky* meaning everything up to the ozone layer.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically, a canopy is used to provide shade while a roof offers more solid protection; canopies filter and roofs protect.  You often hear 'canopy' used to describe the sky-ward protection you experience in a forest or jungle--basically only shade and maybe a little protection from rain.  A cave would offer roof-like protection--shade, protection from rain, *and* protection from big, hard, nasty things that fall from the sky.

These pseudo definitions could be applied to earth's atmosphere in a similar way.  Ask, "Does the atmosphere provide a *shade-like* protection against things from outer space, or does it offer more solid protection?"  I think for most of the big, hard, nasty things that fall from outer space that our atmosphere is only a canopy, but if you are specifically talking about types of radiation that our atmosphere completely reflects or absorbs you could claim that our atmosphere (or sky) is a roof.

Answer (score 3):

Though both refer to some sort of surface above something, I think they are distinct in terms of structural support. That is, a roof is generally a rigid object held in place, while a canopy is looser and hangs above something.

For example, big-tops and forests have canopies while houses and caves have roofs.

Answer (score 2):

In both cases I think the words are acceptable for poetic usage.

> "He slept beneath the roof of the sky;
>   the canopy of the stars"

The words themselves aren't *quite* interchangeable. "Canopy" implies a certain level of permeability, whereas "roof" implies a more solid boundary.

Answer (score 0):

The sky (with your definition) is a thick layer, so I think neither roof nor canopy is an appropriate word.

Comment: but doesn't the sky from the clouds upwards cover the earth like a canopy / roof covers what is below it?

Comment: @nicholas: The clouds count as a canopy. Why would the sky?

Answer (score 0):

It is said the Himalayas are the roof of the earth, so perhaps the sky cannot claim that title?

> would you describe the sky as the roof of the earth or the canopy of the earth.

Yes, I would describe the sky sometimes as the roof of the earth, sometimes as the canopy of the earth. Of course I would also sometimes describe it as the X of the Y, where X and Y are any other handy words that evoke whatever quality of the sky I am trying to communicate. Playground:Gods. Scarred-battleground:Jetliners. TV-Screen:Cosmos. <sub>*Note to self: don't give up day job.*</sub>

So, to answer your question, you first have to know what it is you are trying to communicate. Most people understand the basic (above/below) relationship between sky and earth, so metaphors like roof and canopy might seem a bit, well, banal.

> Sky meaining everything up to the ozone layer

Metaphor is poetic, you should avoid seeming like [Babbage writing to Tennyson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Babbage#Eccentricities)